# Can Android print directly from browser?

Tags: android, html, printing

I am building a web application that takes reservations for rentals, the application needs to be able to print the reservation.

Is it possible to print directly from the browser on the Android platform? Currently my Print button works on desktop, and iOS-based devices. However, Android doesn't seem to even blink when the same button is clicked.

Can printing on the Android platform be done from the browser? Or does it require external applications?

Comment: android has no native printing facilities.

Comment: iOS can print through the browser?

Comment: I shouldn't say for sure, but my iOS simulator brings up a print dialog when I click my print button, I don't have an Airport compatible printer to actually test on however. Where as Android does nothing at all.

Comment: "However, Android doesn't seem to even blink when the same button is clicked" -- please explain **completely and precisely** what you are doing when this button is clicked. In general, Android has no printing capability, and there are many browsers for Android, just as there are many browsers for the desktop.

Comment: Chrome browser on Android 4.3, I have a function that calls the `window.print()` method, Android doesn't even respond with anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into [Google Cloud Printing](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1069693?hl=en)... This is the mechanism used to print for owners of the google chromebooks. It can be used for other purposes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can Android print directly from browser? not very directly but
of corse we can, first of all you have to set your content in a new tab(windows.open()) then you can print this page through browser share, most of the browsers have a share option from menu, find printer from options print it and DONE, that's it.