# how to Implement print functionality on android app

Tags: android, printing, webview

I am New to Android Development. Now I want to Implement print functionality on my android app from a webview. In my webpage there is a  print button while tap on print nothing is happen. I have written `window.print()` comment on print button click to print the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android doesn't have the native support for the printing yet.

Please have a look on the links below:
[Can Android print directly from browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196411/can-android-print-directly-from-browser)
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30512/how-can-i-print-from-android-phone-through-google-chrome-connected-printer-in-la